# Assigning an array to a range of cells in VBA via Objects

Tags: arrays, vba, object, range, cell

I'm generating an automated script for work that searches for data stored in multiple CSV files within a single directory, then consolidates those data into a single workbook. I'm able to extract the data without issues (*i.e.* assign a range of values to an array), but what I can't seem to figure out is how to do the reverse operation.

The error that I always get when executing that part of my script is:

**Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method.**

What I've boiled the cause down to is the combination of `.Range` and `.Cells` (either works just fine by themselves if I change the code to assign a single array value to a single worksheet cell value). The error only arises once I try to assign an *array* to a range of cells. **So, my question is: what method is supported by the object-oriented approach that I'm pursuing for the simplified script I've written below?**

```
Dim testarray(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Integer

testarray(1, 1) = 1
testarray(1, 2) = 2
testarray(2, 1) = 3
testarray(2, 2) = 4

Set Target = Workbooks("_ConsolidatedData.xlsm")
Set wb = Target
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
ws.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 2)).Value = testarray(2, 2)
```

Comment: `ws.Range("A1").Resize(ubound(testarray, 1), ubound(testarray, 2)).Value = testarray`

Comment: `ws.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 2)).Value` won't work unless there's a `With` block you didn't include here.

Comment: Well I'll be. That worked exactly as I need it to in this case. I replaced `.Range("A1")` with `Cells(1,1)` so that it will be compatible with what is upstream of it. I'll try to transplant this into my actual code tomorrow, but I suspect this is the solution.

Comment: Would the correct block be `With ws` in this context?

Comment: Yes but if you use the Resize approach you don't really need a With block there.

Comment: Understood: it's one or the other. I'm wondering, does the `With` block make it so that the `ws` object is referred to by both `.Range` *and* `.Cells`? I was under the impression (inccorectly, obviously) that `ws.Range` was sufficient in this context.

Comment: I just checked this method with my source code and it works perfectly, so I've verified that the question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
ws.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 2)).Value = testarray(2, 2)
```

This line is missing a With Block

```
With ws
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 2)).Value = testarray 'no (2 ,2)
End with
```

Either of these will do what you want though, without needing adjustment if your array size changes:

```
ws.Range("A1").Resize(ubound(testarray, 1), ubound(testarray, 2)).Value = testarray

ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(ubound(testarray, 1), ubound(testarray, 2)).Value = testarray
```